# Number of processes in a single JVM instance

Tags: java, process, jvm

It seems one VM instance can only run one process (real OS or VMware can run multiple process in it).

Is it right?

Comment: One VM instance is one process, but it can have as many Threads as it would like to. And it is possible to run many JVMs beside each other in a single OS instance. And zou can run many OS instances beside each other in a virtualized environment.

Comment: Your language is confused, which may explain your confusion. A VM instance *is* a process. The VM itself doesn't get any say in that: the operating system does it.

Answer (score 2):

Every instance of your Java Virtual Machine is a single `java` process running some bytecode. Inside each process, you can handle several [threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) if you need some concurrency. If you absolutely need various distinct `java` processes in your application, you can use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) to start a new child process, corresponding to a new JVM instance.